# Access disk information in swift (Cocoa Disk API?)

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm trying to build a program that will format a USB. I would like there to be a menu that the user can pick from listing the possible drive choices. However, I'm having a hard time finding any information about interacting with drives in Swift. Certainly there is an API or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Certainly there is an API or something, since Swift is the native language.

This is a nonsense statement, since APIs and languages are orthogonal. And Swift is not "the native language". It's one supported language, high-level, and only relatively recently added, so unlikely to be used by much of the system.

Anyway, to list volumes (which are not the same as drives), there's `NSFileManager`'s `mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(_:options:)`.

To work with volumes, disks, and devices at a somewhat lower level, there's the Disk Arbitration API.

At an even lower level there are BSD devices. There's also the IOKit Storage family.

Most likely, though, for what you're trying to do, you'll want to write a wrapper around the `diskutil` command-line tool. Many of its commands take a `-plist` option to facilitate interpretation of its output by programs, which can use `NSPropertyListSerialization` to parse the resulting property lists.